# Haskell error "parse error on input 'fib'"?

Tags: haskell

I was trying to create a typeclass with a function named primeFib that when called with `n`, returns the n first primes on the Fibonacci sequence.

Here is my code:

```
class PrimeirosPrimos x where
   primeFib :: x -> [x]
   primeFat :: x -> [x]
   fib :: x -> x -> x -> [x]
   ePrimo :: x -> x -> x -> Bool

instance PrimeirosPrimos Integer where
    primeFib n =  fib 2 3 n 

    fib a b 0 = []
    fib a b n = if ePrimo a (sqrt a) 2
                then [a] ++ fib b (a+b) (n-1)
                else fib b (a+b) n

    ePrimo a lim num | num>lim = True
                     | a/num <= 0  = False
                     | otherwise = ePrimo a lim (num+1)
```

But when I try to compile it, ghci returns:

```
qt.hs:11:5: parse error on input 'fib'

Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't get that error. I get other errors (expects different type of value to `sqrt` and `/`). Perhaps, better be more specific, quote the rest of the code?

Comment: Make sure there all the indendation is done using spaces, not tabs.

Comment: Bah!  I use tabs in all my Haskell.  You *do* have to either use them consistently and with discipline, or not use them at all.  <SP><SP><SP><SP> is rather different to Haskell then <TAB> or <TAB><SP><SP>.